# How to pass variable of paragraphs type to another preprocess function

Tags: 8, theming, paragraphs

I want to override the fontawesomeicons.html.twig (Fontawesome Module). But I only want to do this for "my-very-special-paragraphs-type" and not in general. I think it is a good idea to declare a variable of "my-very-special-paragraphs-type" in a preprocess function and use the variable in the twig-file.

```
function mytheme_preprocess() {
  $var = my-very-special-paragraphs-type
}
```

the fontawesomeicons.html.twig:

```
{% if var == 'my-very-special-paragraphs-type' %}  
<div class="fontawesome-icons pb-4 t-a-c">
    <span class="fa-stack fa-4x">{{ icons }}</span>
</div>
{% else %}
<div class="fontawesome-icons">
   {% if layers == '1' %}
      <span class="fa-layers fa-fw">{{ icons }}</span>
   {% else %}
      {{ icons }}
   {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

But I do not know how to do this. Can anybody help?

This is the hook of fontawesome module:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was quite a ride.

First of all: I didn't got this running in the theme. I needed to create a custom module AND move its implementation of the fontawesomeicons hook last.

Next thing was: `hook_preprocess_fontawesomeicons` doesn't contain a hint of the parent entity the icons are used in. So I used `hook_preprocess_field` first to pass the paragraph type over to [`drupal_static()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/8.2.x) and retrieved it back then in `hook_preprocess_fontawesomeicons`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {

  if ($hook == 'fontawesomeicons') {

    // Run MYMODULE_preprocess_fontawesomeicons() last.
    $group = $implementations['MYMODULE'];
    unset($implementations['MYMODULE']);
    $implementations['MYMODULE'] = $group;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_field__FIELD_TYPE().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_field__fontawesome_icon(&$variables) {

  if ($variables['element']['#entity_type'] == 'paragraph') {

    $paragraph = $variables['element']['#object'];

    $ptype = &drupal_static('paragraph_type', TRUE);
    $ptype = $paragraph->getType();
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_fontawesomeicons(&$variables) {

  $ptype = &drupal_static('paragraph_type', FALSE);

  if ($ptype) {
    $variables['paragraph_type'] = $ptype;
  }
}
```

Inside any variation of `fontawesomeicons.html.twig` you now can:

```
{% if paragraph_type == 'my-very-special-paragraphs-type' %}
  {# do your magic here #}
{% endif %}
```

---

I never heard of [`drupal_static()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/8.2.x) until today. Read more:

- [How do I pass data between hooks that don't interact?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/32354/15055)
- [Share a value between two different hooks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/9450/15055)

Comment: I can not make it run. I install the module but it is not working. Not with or without s. I use it in a nested paragraph and webfont with CSS. I have cleared allways the cache and tried both paragraph types.

Comment: @lesleyn. – I got it working that way. Would you upload your resulting module maybe on GitHub and ping me the link here, so I can review?